# Java - Printing an unfilled diamond using nested for loops

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I am new to learning Java and I am trying to print an unfilled diamond using asterisks. The height of the diamond has to be based on user input. My code currently prints out a filled diamond based on user input but I cannot figure out how to print an unfilled one. Every time I change one of the loops it messes something else up. All help is appreciated!

```
public static void diamond(){
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int k = 0;
   int height = 0;

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("How tall do you want the diamond to be: ");
   height = in.nextInt();

   for (k = 1; k <= (height + 1) / 2; k++) {
       for (i = 0; i < height - k; i++) {
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
       for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
           System.out.print("* ");
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }

   for (k = ((height + 1) / 2); k < height; k++) {
       for (i = 1; i < k; i++) { 
           System.out.print(" "); 
       }
       for (j = 0; j < height - k; j++) { 
           System.out.print(" *");
       }
       System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the method modified for printing an unfilled diamond. An if condition has been added to the inner loops.

```
public static void diamond() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int height = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How tall do you want the diamond to be: ");
    height = in.nextInt();

    for (k = 1; k <= (height + 1) / 2; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < height - k; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == (k - 1)) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (k = ((height + 1) / 2); k < height; k++) {
        for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j < height - k; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == (height - k - 1)) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```